# How are light beams even possible?

Tags: waves, electromagnetic-radiation, visible-light, diffraction

Since light is a wave, and when a wave passes through an opening it diffracts in a way that spreads it in all directions as Huygens explained (in the picture below).

[image]

How is it then that we can have light beams where light doesn't spread in all directions, but is rather focused, with only minor diffraction?

Comment: All ‘beams’ will spread.

Comment: Diffraction depends on the cross-section of the beam. The narrower the beam the faster it spreads. Full Maxwell's equations would show this, but [Gaussian Optics](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Gaussian_beam) provides a much easier exposition.

Answer (score 1):

The Huygens wavelets (in your figure) interfere, with some reinforcing each other and others canceling each other. The result is a sin[x]/x (or sinc function) beam pattern.

Your figure only shows the wavelets close to the aperture, near field, further away, far field, a sinc pattern would be seen.